# Node webkit back/forward button state detection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, node-webkit

Working on a Node Webkit project, we have in-app navigation using back/forward buttons, and hiding the native navbar.

I'm interested in being able to detect the back button state, so that when there's nowhere to go, I can reflect a disabled state in the UI.

What I mean is, for example, in the scenario when a user navigated through some pages, but never clicked `back`, the `forward` button should be disabled, as clicking it has no action. The same for the first page navigated to, or after the user clicks `back` all the way back to the start.

Is there an option to detect the status of Node Webkit button status, or even just pull out the next item in the stack? I'd like to use the (hidden) native button in order to reflect its state on mine.

(I must admit I have no code examples to actually show, as I couldn't find anything useful. But I'm mostly looking for something such as `nw.backbutton.stack[0]`, or `nw.backbutton.isEnabled()`. Obviously, those are useless as I just made them up for the example.)

Thanks from ahead.

Comment: Note: There's an open issue on GitHub requesting this, from about 2 years ago. https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1507

Answer (score 0):

you can use JS:

```
var callback = function(e){
    if (e.which == 37) {
        console.log('left!');
    } else if (e.which == 39) {
        console.log('right!');
    } else {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
};
window.addEventListener('keydown',callback,false);
```

Tested on Mac, might be different event numbers on windows.

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez what did you mean? I though you wanted to know if the user pressed back or forward button, which can be done using the code above

Comment: I want to know the state of the back button. If it's disabled or not.